# Alexa testing console doesn't ask to me

Tags: testing, alexa-skills-kit

I'm working with an alexa skill, I tested it in AWS and it works but when i go to test tab to try to ask something the only result is "  " what should be the problem? my skill name is  "test" that has an intent called "sensor" that recive a {sensor}variable type. To trigger Alexa I use to ask "Alexa, start test sensor 1234" but the answer is the one I indicated above.

```
    "interactionModel": {
    "languageModel": {
        "invocationName": "test",
        "intents": [
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.NavigateHomeIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "sensor",
                "slots": [
                    {
                        "name": "sensorid",
                        "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
                    }
                ],
                "samples": [
                    "sensore {sensorid}",

                ]
            }
        ],
        "types": []
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Write down the code of the lambda, in particular the Intent that you mention otherwise is difficult to understand your question

Comment: I have just edit the post

Comment: In developer console you have to write numbers as words and you don't have to write `Alexa` when you open the skill. So try `open test for sensor one thousand two hundred thirty four" or something like that

Comment: ok, thank you so much. Grazie mille ;)